# How to scan the number of words from user to print the string?

Tags: c, string

In one of my assignment question first i need to scan number of words from user and then after i need to find the particular word(word sample in example) in a given string.

Example:

```
Input

5                                     // Where 5 indicates the number of word
This is a sample input                //need to find the word sample

Output:
4
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. If you don't know where to start, consult your C tutorial or lectures on "input/output" and "string manipulation" topics. SO is not a free homework writing site, but we can help once you try something and encounter a problem.

Comment: Hi Denis I know how to count the number of words in a string but scanning the number of words from user is new thing for me. it will be helpful if you provide just how to scan number of words

Comment: You can scan the whole input from user into a string using `fgets` or something simillar, then you'll have the problem you already know how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scanf` to read the number of words, then read them one by one and compare.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define WORD_MAX_LEN 20

#define SEARCH_VAL "sample"


int main()
{
    int num_of_words, i=0;
    char word[WORD_MAX_LEN];


    //read input words
    scanf("%d", &num_of_words);

    // search
    while (i++ < num_of_words)
    {
        scanf("%s", word);
        if (strcmp(word, SEARCH_VAL) == 0)
        {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", word);`, like `gets()` are both poor programming.  Use a width limit or some other function.

Comment: output apparently should be printed after all the words have been entered